# Raster' object is not iterable

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of cell counts in new raster and the new raster is created from an old raster based on the Value > 14. In my code, 1st for loop is for original raster and keeping the value and count fields in a dictionary. Then, creating new raster using Value > 14. The 2nd for loop is for the new raster and keeping its value and counts of in a new dictionary and finally calculating the percentage.

However, I am getting an error on the 2nd for loop. The error says:

> 'Raster' object is not iterable

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/Neshanic_Python"

outws="C:/Subhasis/Test/Neshanic_Python/extract"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# set local variable
inraster = ["01367620-r-r"]

for i in inraster:
    flds = ("VALUE", "COUNT") 
    dct = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, flds)} 
    sumcnt = sum(dct.values())
    newraster = ExtractByAttributes(str(i), "VALUE>=14")
    for j in newraster:
        flds1 = ("VALUE", "COUNT")
        dct1 = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(j, flds)}
        sumcnt1 = sum(dct1.values())
        percentage=(sumcnt/sumcnt1)
        print percentage
```

Comment: Maybe the new raster needs an attribute table built (see [Build Raster Attribute Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m2000000)). Also, the `dct1 = ...` line needs to end with `flds1` not `flds`.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure why you are making the second raster. Can you just calculate the statistics from the dictionary of values?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you do not need to make a second raster to accomplish this. Rather, use Python to sub-set the dictionary to select only the desired values. This should both bypass the problem, and run faster.

```
# original dictionary from raster
dct = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, flds)}
sumcnt = sum(dct.values())

# new dictionary with only values >= 14
dct1 = {k:v for (k,v) in dct.items() if k >= 14}
sumcnt1 = sum(dct1.values())

percentage = float(sumcnt1) / float(sumcnt)
```

Comment: Hi Erica, Thanks for your quick response. I tried your code, The percentage I found is 1, which should be less than 1. I am thinking it is calculating the same counts in the second dictionary.

Comment: I had `sumcnt1` and `sumcnt` in the wrong places in `percentage`, I've reversed that. There's a float/int problem still...

Comment: I changed numerator and denominator in percentage and got "0" value. Then tried printing dct and dct 1. In dct1, I got all the value similar to dct except the 1st vale and counts. see the print of both dictionary in the next comment.

Comment: {2: 2, 3: 469, 4: 13285, 5: 76108, 6: 171267, 7: 208442, 8: 164431, 9: 104373, 10: 60528, 11: 33130, 12: 19117, 13: 12222, 14: 11536, 15: 10512, 16: 11985, 17: 9879, 18: 11079, 19: 16356, 20: 38192, 21: 78030, 22: 71292, 23: 48962, 24: 24341, 25: 3894, 26: 2440, 27: 746, 28: 318, 29: 396}
{3: 469, 4: 13285, 5: 76108, 6: 171267, 7: 208442, 8: 164431, 9: 104373, 10: 60528, 11: 33130, 12: 19117, 13: 12222, 14: 11536, 15: 10512, 16: 11985, 17: 9879, 18: 11079, 19: 16356, 20: 38192, 21: 78030, 22: 71292, 23: 48962, 24: 24341, 25: 3894, 26: 2440, 27: 746, 28: 318, 29: 396}

Comment: OK, it is filtering on the count instead of the value. Change `v >= 14` to `k >= 14`. Also make sure the two `sumcnt` variables are explicitly cast as float (otherwise it's rounding the percentage, which will always be an int of 0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now got it. Can I ask you a general question?

Comment: Sure (although if it's moderately complex, another Question would also work)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15919/discussion-between-erica-and-inception).

Answer (score 3):

The real issue lies in the line:

```
for j in newraster:
```

where you are indeed trying to loop (iterate) through a raster object, which is not "loopable". As Erica points out, this won't work and is not necessary.

I think you are simply trying to figure out what % of the cells have a value >= 14, correct? Erica has a correct answer - althoiugh populating a new dictionary with the values >= 14 is not necessary I think. Another correct answer would look like this:

```
valueDct = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, flds)}
valSum = sum(valueDict.values())
valFilterSum = sum([valueDct[i] for i in valueDct if i >= 14])
percentage = float(valFilterSum) / valSum
```

Comment: I had valFilterSum list comp wrong - now correct!

Comment: Thank you for your post. I got the answer using Erica's code.

Comment: Hmm. Alright, I would do from next time onwards..

Comment: Indeed, this is a more concise approach. I tend to err on the side of unnecessarily verbose code when introducing programming structure, but a tighter structure is what I would personally use.